# wordpress, detecting number of widets inside a div

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using wordpress and have come at a point that i have to hide the div if there is no widget displayed in it.
 can some one tell me the code for detection of number of widgets displayed in a specific area.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'your-widget-area' ) ) : ?>
<!--This div will not display if there is no active widgets
     so place your div inside if condition-->
 <div>

<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'your-widget-area' ); ?>

 </div>        
<?php endif; ?>
```